# Use of "Not getting"

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, multiple-negation

I often come across a sentence in spoken English (and sometimes in written English as well) that I think is grammatically incorrect. The sentence is

> It's never a bad idea **not getting** advice from XYZ.

Although comprehensible, it sounds as though it could be better rephrased, but I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: 'It's not a good idea to seek advice from XYZ.' Avoid using too many negatives.

Comment: never - (negative); bad - (negative); not - (negative) => (-1)(-1)(-1) = -1. Hence, it is also possible to say it this way: "It's a good idea **not** to get/seek advice from XYZ."

Comment: if you need to use frequency-related word then, "It's **always** a bad idea to seek advice from XYZ." (always and never being polar opposites)

Comment: Spoken: "(We'd) Better not listen to XYZ." Written: "It's recommended not to listen to XYZ." (If I understand your "getting" correctly; otherwise, shin's "seek" is good.) -- I wonder if your example really is grammatically incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

**Not getting** literally means **to not receive**.

The sentence uses a **double negative**, which can be confusing and requires close attention to unravel. Since both negatives negate each other, the equivalent meaning is:

> It's a bad idea **getting** advice from XYZ.

Here, **getting** can be equivalent to **seeking** or **obtaining** (where the listener is proactive), it can also mean **receiving** (where the listener is passive).

> It's a bad idea **seeking** advice from XYZ.
>   It's a bad idea **receiving** advice from XYZ.

A better equivalent would be:

> It is best **to avoid** advice from XYZ.

Answer (score 0):

It is slang. It is a joke, really. You are saying the opposite of a common saying.  The complex grammatical answers aren’t helpful. Its sarcasm.